# Strange vertical white spacer

Tags: html, margin

I started to write my code as always and I got this strange vertical spacers between `header` and `section` as seen below. This is something very noobish but cant deal with it.

**CSS**

```
.container {
    background:#000;
}
.pos-center {
    background:#000;
    width:1080px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.slider {
    background:url(slider.jpg) no-repeat;
    height:338px;
    width:1080px;
    border-bottom:#ff5300 3px solid;    
}

.nav {
    background:#F00 ;
    height:40px;

}
.nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="pos-center">
                <div class="slider">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="pos-center">
                <div class="nav">
                    <ul>
                       <li><a href="#">Zadaj Pytanie</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Komentarze</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Dodaj do Ulubionych</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Nasze Aukcje</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">O Nas</a></li>                
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: It's coming from the browsers default CSS it adds to the page. Specifically a margin to the `unordered list`. You might want to look at using a CSS reset, such as this one - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ to get rid of the browsers default styling. You might also want to use some sort of developer tools to inspect the HTML and to see what CSS properties are being applied to it. `Firebug` - Firefox for example, or `Chrome's Developer tools.`

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `ul` inside `.nav` has a `margin-top`.

Set it to `margin-top: 0` and you should be fine.

```css
.container {
    background:#000;
}
.pos-center {
    background:#000;
    width:1080px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.slider {
    background:url(slider.jpg) no-repeat;
    height:338px;
    width:1080px;
    border-bottom:#ff5300 3px solid;    
}

.nav {
    background:#F00 ;
    height:40px;

}
.nav ul {
  margin-top: 0; //Here
}
.nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="pos-center">
                <div class="slider">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="pos-center">
                <div class="nav">
                    <ul>
                       <li><a href="#">Zadaj Pytanie</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Komentarze</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Dodaj do Ulubionych</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Nasze Aukcje</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">O Nas</a></li>                
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works , Thank you very much , and have a nice day .
I got littel reputation and cant give you prop for this.